# Unexpected SIGSEGV while using std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, stl, segmentation-fault

While writing code that uses std::unordered_map container I've encountered issues with SIGSEGV being reported under specific circumstances. I will explain details using code. So here is the class using mentioned container:

```
constexpr std::uint8_t MAX_COMPONENTS = 32;

using Entity = std::uint32_t;

template <typename T>
class ComponentArray
{
public:
    void addComponentToArray(const Entity entity, T &&component)
    {
        assert(not entityFound(entity));

        const auto newIndex = componentArraySize_;
        entityToIndex_[entity] = newIndex;
        indexToEntity_[newIndex] = entity;
        componentArray_[newIndex] = std::move(component);

        ++componentArraySize_;
    }

private:
    bool entityFound(const Entity entity) const
    {
        return entityToIndex_.find(entity) != entityToIndex_.cend();
    }

private:
    std::size_t componentArraySize_ = 0;

    std::array<T, MAX_COMPONENTS> componentArray_;
    std::unordered_map<Entity, std::size_t> entityToIndex_;
    std::unordered_map<std::size_t, Entity> indexToEntity_;
};
```

Here is function using functionality of ComponentArray

```
struct Transform
{
    int x = 0;
};

void test0()
{
    ComponentArray<Transform> carr{};

    constexpr int entitiesCount = 32;

    for (int i = 0; i < entitiesCount; ++i)
        carr.addComponentToArray(i, Transform{});
}
```

Notice that value of entitiesCount is 32 and for the range 0 - 32 the code will work as expected, i.e. no SIGSEGV reported. However if I change it to 33 (or any value above that) it will crash. Here is valgrind report:

```
==17193== Invalid write of size 8
==17193==    at 0x484F7ED: memset (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17193==    by 0x109EE0: std::_Hashtable<unsigned int, std::pair<unsigned int const, unsigned long>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, unsigned long> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<unsigned int>, std::hash<unsigned int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::clear() (in /home/devel/cpp/draft/test4)
==17193==    by 0x109E48: std::_Hashtable<unsigned int, std::pair<unsigned int const, unsigned long>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, unsigned long> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<unsigned int>, std::hash<unsigned int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::~_Hashtable() (in /home/devel/cpp/draft/test4)
==17193==    by 0x1097B4: std::unordered_map<unsigned int, unsigned long, std::hash<unsigned int>, std::equal_to<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, unsigned long> > >::~unordered_map() (in /home/devel/cpp/draft/test4)
==17193==    by 0x10949F: ComponentArray<Transform>::~ComponentArray() (in /home/devel/cpp/draft/test4)
==17193==    by 0x1092C7: test0() (in /home/devel/cpp/draft/test4)
==17193==    by 0x109308: main (in /home/devel/cpp/draft/test4)
==17193==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==17193== 
==17193== 
==17193== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==17193==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==17193==    at 0x484F7ED: memset (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17193==    by 0x109EE0: std::_Hashtable<unsigned int, std::pair<unsigned int const, unsigned long>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, unsigned long> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<unsigned int>, std::hash<unsigned int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::clear() (in /home/devel/cpp/draft/test4)
==17193==    by 0x109E48: std::_Hashtable<unsigned int, std::pair<unsigned int const, unsigned long>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, unsigned long> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<unsigned int>, std::hash<unsigned int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::~_Hashtable() (in /home/devel/cpp/draft/test4)
==17193==    by 0x1097B4: std::unordered_map<unsigned int, unsigned long, std::hash<unsigned int>, std::equal_to<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, unsigned long> > >::~unordered_map() (in /home/devel/cpp/draft/test4)
==17193==    by 0x10949F: ComponentArray<Transform>::~ComponentArray() (in /home/devel/cpp/draft/test4)
==17193==    by 0x1092C7: test0() (in /home/devel/cpp/draft/test4)
==17193==    by 0x109308: main (in /home/devel/cpp/draft/test4)
==17193==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==17193==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==17193==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==17193==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==17193==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==17193== 
==17193== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17193==     in use at exit: 73,176 bytes in 2 blocks
==17193==   total heap usage: 73 allocs, 71 frees, 75,904 bytes allocated
==17193== 
==17193== LEAK SUMMARY:
==17193==    definitely lost: 472 bytes in 1 blocks
==17193==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17193==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17193==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==17193==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17193== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==17193== 
==17193== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==17193== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

But it is not over. Another Surprise is fact that if I make change so

```
struct Transform
{
    // no members
};
```

then I can make entitesCount any number (gr_eq than 0 of course) and code will work fine. This is really confusing for me as unordered_map inside ComponentArray maps std::uint32_t to size_t and vice versa then how T=Component with simple int value (or any other type) correlates with this error. I was rarely using unordered_map until this day so I believe there is something I am missing here. Could anyone give me any advice how to progress with this issue?

Best regards,
0x707

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] as required here please.

Comment: When you increase `entitiesCount` do you also increase `MAX_COMPONENTS` or just run off the end of the array?

Comment: "32 and for the range 0 - 32 the code.." => "32 and for the range 0 - 31 the code..", 32 is not a valid index for an array of size 32

Comment: Of course it fails, you have a hard coded limit of 32 entries

Comment: Pretty much every standard library implementation has a diagnostic mode, where it diagnoses some usage errors at the cost of performance. Activate that and it will probably tell you were this code went wrong. Note the advise to extract a [mcve] as well. Not only is your Q off-topic without it, it also helps you focus on the problem as well. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @RetiredNinja I feel so stupid. This is it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As @RetiredNinja observed in the comment I forgot about MAX_COMPONENTS restriction update when adding more than 32 elements.